# Youtube-dl Unable to download webpage CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED

Tags: python, youtube-dl

it works in the terminal  `youtube-dl --no-check-certificate https://youtu.be/PsO6ZnUZI0g`

but in the code, even though I have `'no_check_certificate': True,` but when I run  `ydl.download(['https://youtu.be/PsO6ZnUZI0g'])`

it still says that `Unable to download webpage: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)>`

Does anyone know a solution? Thank you!

Comment: Can you add a code snippet?

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. We can help if you [edit] your question and add your code as a [mcve].